My streamlit folium map crashes when I apply groupby operations on my original h3 dataframe
I am developing a geo app with streamlit focused on plotting Uber H3 hexagons that have different type of  of feature groups to be plotted over a folium map. The dataframe I have with the information of the hexagons looks something like
                 hex_id  hex_resolution    region  latitude  longitude  a__points  a_mean_value  b_points  b_mean_value
0       8b664175a6c9fff              11  Cacahual  3.380089 -67.729749                       3                  113.829310                          16                        0.000000
1       8b664e9958a5fff              11  Cacahual  3.159770 -67.741843                       2                   49.890930                          19                       85.263158
2       8b66412a5d51fff              11  Cacahual  3.426441 -67.520657                       2                   48.978256                          20                       90.000000
3       8b66412b50eefff              11  Cacahual  3.412557 -67.573996                       4                   49.393820                          17                       96.470588
4       8b664104ab4afff              11  Cacahual  3.606199 -67.513259                       4                   48.174440                          16                       99.375000

For displaying the map I am using streamlit-folium. I have different zoom values to display different resolutions of the h3 hexagons and I do the conversion between each of the resolutions using h3pandas with the following function
def charge_df(file_path, resolution, first_n_rows = None ):

    #charges the original dataframe
    df =  pd.read_csv(file_path)

    # conversion of the original resolution to a new one with h3pandas
    if first_n_rows:
        h3df = df\
            .head(first_n_rows)\
            .h3.geo_to_h3(resolution, 
                        lat_col = "latitude", 
                        lng_col = "longitude")
    else:
        h3df = df\
            .h3.geo_to_h3(resolution, hex_resolution  latitude  longitude  carbon_removals_points  carbon_removals_mean_value  tropical_tree_cover_points  tropical_tree_cover_mean_value                                           geometry
h3_05                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
85664107fffffff            11.0  3.642390 -67.515120                2.538934                   67.715361                   16.963115                      100.343107  POLYGON ((-67.57841 3.7442, -67.62704 3.67422,...
8566410ffffffff            11.0  3.543830 -67.636296                2.428571                   93.160690                   17.000000                       65.569301  POLYGON ((-67.71448 3.68601, -67.76322 3.61592...
85664117fffffff            11.0  3.751133 -67.518407                2.524590                   97.021296                   17.016393                      140.074436  POLYGON ((-67.56855 3.89578, -67.61715 3.82594...
85664123fffffff            11.0  3.414848 -67.423126                2.697868                   66.142274                   17.145505                       80.192160  POLYGON ((-67.46216 3.49883, -67.51075 3.42869...
85664127fffffff            11.0  3.356174 -67.347446                2.576923                   76.884983                   16.879121                       79.051022  POLYGON ((-67.33614 3.40529, -67.38464 3.33512...
8566412bfffffff            11.0  3.360755 -67.560013                2.599462                   75.963019                   17.118280                       60.881480  POLYGON ((-67.59816 3.4404, -67.64685 3.37015,...
8566412ffffffff            11.0  3.287853 -67.446837                2.626781                   73.198487                   17.128205                       61.123238  POLYGON ((-67.47197 3.3468, -67.52059 3.27652,...
85664133fffffff            11.0  3.557516 -67.454476                2.578947                   68.361575                   17.093301                       89.720296  POLYGON ((-67.45236 3.65065, -67.50092 3.58065...
                        lat_col = "latitude", 
                        lng_col = "longitude")
    
    gdfh3 = h3df.h3.h3_to_geo_boundary()
    st.write(gdfh3.columns)
    return gdfh3

This function creates a new geopandas dataframe based on the original that looks like
hex_resolution  latitude  longitude  a_points  a_mean_value  b_cover_points  b_mean_value                                           geometry
h3_05                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
85664107fffffff            11.0  3.642390 -67.515120                2.538934                   67.715361                   16.963115                      100.343107  POLYGON ((-67.57841 3.7442, -67.62704 3.67422,...
8566410ffffffff            11.0  3.543830 -67.636296                2.428571                   93.160690                   17.000000                       65.569301  POLYGON ((-67.71448 3.68601, -67.76322 3.61592...
85664117fffffff            11.0  3.751133 -67.518407                2.524590                   97.021296                   17.016393                      140.074436  POLYGON ((-67.56855 3.89578, -67.61715 3.82594...
85664123fffffff            11.0  3.414848 -67.423126                2.697868                   66.142274                   17.145505                       80.192160  POLYGON ((-67.46216 3.49883, -67.51075 3.42869...
85664127fffffff            11.0  3.356174 -67.347446                2.576923                   76.884983                   16.879121                       79.051022  POLYGON ((-67.33614 3.40529, -67.38464 3.33512...
8566412bfffffff            11.0  3.360755 -67.560013                2.599462                   75.963019                   17.118280                       60.881480  POLYGON ((-67.59816 3.4404, -67.64685 3.37015,...
8566412ffffffff            11.0  3.287853 -67.446837                2.626781                   73.198487                   17.128205                       61.123238  POLYGON ((-67.47197 3.3468, -67.52059 3.27652,...
85664133fffffff            11.0  3.557516 -67.454476                2.578947                   68.361575                   17.093301                       89.720296  POLYGON ((-67.45236 3.65065, -67.50092 3.58065...

Where the index is the id of the new hex resolution. As you can see, there are duplicated indexes, and that's why I wanted to make a modification to the function I showed before, so that it now calculates the mean value of the duplicated indexes and grouped them by the id. The function looks now like
def new_charge_df(file_path, resolution, first_n_rows = None ):
    df =  pd.read_csv(file_path)
    if first_n_rows:
        h3df = df\
            .head(first_n_rows)\
            .h3.geo_to_h3(resolution, 
                        lat_col = "latitude", 
                        lng_col = "longitude")
    else:
        h3df = df\
            .h3.geo_to_h3(resolution, 
                        lat_col = "latitude", 
                        lng_col = "longitude")
        
    resolution_column = h3df.index.name
    h3df = h3df.groupby(resolution_column).mean(numeric_only=True).reset_index().set_index(resolution_column)
    gdfh3 = h3df.h3.h3_to_geo_boundary()
    st.write(gdfh3.columns)
    return gdfh3

However, even though before this modification the code was working correctly in the part of the plotting, that looks like
# Sidebar widgets
    zoom, feature_group_to_add = sidebar_widgets()
    
    # Load the data
    first_n_rows = 10000
    cacahual_gdfh3 = charge_df(file_path="./db/cacahual_db.csv", 
                               resolution = zoom - 3,
                               first_n_rows = first_n_rows)
    print(cacahual_gdfh3)
    
    # Create the feature groups and the colormaps
    fg_cm_dic = {"A mean value": create_feature_group(gdf=cacahual_gdfh3, 
                                                                   data_to_plot="a_mean_value", 
                                                                   label_to_plot="A mean value (m.u.)", 
                                                                   feature_group_name="A mean value"),
                 "B mean value": create_feature_group(gdf=cacahual_gdfh3, 
                                                                       data_to_plot="b_cover_mean_value", 
                                                                       label_to_plot="B mean value (m.u.)", 
                                                                       feature_group_name="B mean value"),
                 "None": [None, None]}
    
    # Create the map
    m = folium.Map(location=[3.5252777777778, -67.415833333333],
                   max_bounds = True)
    
    # Add the colormap to the map
    if fg_cm_dic[feature_group_to_add][1]:
        colormap = fg_cm_dic[feature_group_to_add][1]
        colormap.add_to(m)
    
    # Obtain the feature group to add
    fg = fg_cm_dic[feature_group_to_add][0]
        
    # Display the map
    st_folium(m, 
              feature_group_to_add=fg, 
              zoom = st.session_state["zoom"])

After the modification for finding the mean value in the groupby, I am getting the following error
AssertionError: The field region is not available in the data. Choose from: ('hex_resolution', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'a_points', 'a_mean_value', 'b_points', 'b_mean_value').
Traceback:

File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/exec_code.py", line 88, in exec_func_with_error_handling
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 590, in code_to_exec
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/juanessao2000/Documents/PRINCIPAL/PROYECTOS/TRABAJO-PLANETAI/Projects/Mapbox/Test-repository/app.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/juanessao2000/Documents/PRINCIPAL/PROYECTOS/TRABAJO-PLANETAI/Projects/Mapbox/Test-repository/app.py", line 51, in main
    st_folium(m,
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit_folium/__init__.py", line 350, in st_folium
    feature_group_string += _get_feature_group_string(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit_folium/__init__.py", line 163, in _get_feature_group_string
    feature_group_to_add.render()
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/folium/map.py", line 80, in render
    super().render(**kwargs)
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/branca/element.py", line 681, in render
    element.render(**kwargs)
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/folium/features.py", line 835, in render
    super().render()
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/folium/map.py", line 80, in render
    super().render(**kwargs)
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/branca/element.py", line 681, in render
    element.render(**kwargs)
File "/home/juanessao2000/.local/share/virtualenvs/Test-repository-vctNLQQo/lib/python3.11/site-packages/folium/features.py", line 1191, in render
    value in keys

What could be caussing this problem? I cannot find a reason for this error neither I find how to search for other questions in forums that could help me. Any comment on the matter is of great help. Thanks in advance!

Solved! resulted that the mean(numeric_only = True) only conserves the columns where there are numeric values, and the "region" column was not taken into account.
